# i getting error while npm run dev its not complaine

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, compiler-errors, node-modules

```
87% sealing module hashinginternal/crypto/hash.js:84
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
^
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or
```

an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

```
    at Hash.update (internal/crypto/hash.js:84:11)re
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop\restaurant\no
de_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:49:14)
    at NormalModule.updateHash (C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop\restaurant\node_
modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:1115:8)
    at Compilation.createModuleHashes (C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop\restauran
t\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:2817:12)
    at C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop\restaurant\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compi
lation.js:2155:11
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop
\restaurant\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:10:1
)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop
\restaurant\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop\restaurant\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compi
lation.js:2115:36
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop
\restaurant\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:10:1
)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop
\restaurant\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop\restaurant
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c webpack --progress --confi
g=C:\\Users\\#root\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\restaurant\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\se
tup\\webpack.config.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\#root\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-11T16_06_38_59
9Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop\restaurant
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c mix

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\#root\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-11T16_06_39_65
1Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\#root\OneDrive\Desktop\restaurant
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm run development

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\#root\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-11T16_06_39_93
3Z-debug.log
```

i try
npm chache clean --force
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm run dev

this not working
my project is on laravel 8
using ui^3.0
vue--auth
and i do fresh installing too but does'nt work too
my another procject using jetstream :livewire npm working just fine
sry spelling misktake

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and had to change my package.json. It looked like:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14"
    },
```

But worked after I changed it to:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2"
    },
```

I noticed that this error only came up when I used `mix.sass()` in webpack.mix.js.